# problem booting crusty old windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, boot, bsod, acer-aspire

I have an acer aspire laptop running Windows XP home.

I believe I have some virus on it, I'm not sure--I mostly just run linux in a VM on it so I wasn't too worried. I'm not sure if that virus caused this problem.

The laptop wasn't recognizing my USB hard drive for some reason so I decided to restart it. When it started up, it got past the memory test, past the boot screen, (but it paused right here on a blank screen for awhile) and flashed the desktop once (like it does just before the login screen) and then crashed. I got a quick BSOD and then it restarted. Then it tried to boot again, etc etc infinite loop of failure.

Well, before trying safe mode, I disabled automatic restart on system crash so I could read the blue screen. There wasn't anything important on it, it said

```
*** STOP: 0x00000000 (0xC0000000 0x,.... )

beginning physical memory dump
physical memory dump complete
```

That's not verbatim (obviously) but it didn't help me.

so I booted in safe mode, and it stopped on the driver `gagp30kx.sys`  and then restarted (and infinite loop of failure again).

I burned a recovery CD and tried that. It loaded it, and I went into repair mode. I ran `chkdsk` and then disabled the AGP driver. Same thing on booting in safe mode except it stopped at mup.sys instead.

I enabled the AGP driver again, and ran `chkdsk` again from the CD. It said it found problems but didn't say it fixed them. So I ran it a second time, and it said "performing additional checking or recovery" lots of times (I can't tell how many, they went above the screen top). I tried booting again and no luck.

Every time I run `chkdsk` after trying to boot again it says it found and fixed more errors.

I think it might be whatever driver is after the AGP driver, but I don't know what it is or how to find out.

Can anyone help me fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can boot into a [recovery console](http://www.windowsnetworking.com/articles_tutorials/wxprcons.html?printversion) then you should be able to run the following commands:

1. `chkdsk /r` - repairs faults on the drive. Typically errors loading files are because the file system is failing.
2. `sfc /scannow` - Ensures windows protected files haven't been compromised. You may need to [slipstream](http://lifehacker.com/386526/slipstream-service-pack-3-into-your-windows-xp-installation-cd) a Windows CD with the latest service pack.

Comment: sfc won't run in recovery console

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest burning a live linux cd such as knoppix.  Boot from the CD and copy off all the data you need.  Then you can format the drive and reinstall windows if you need to without worrying about losing anything.

Comment: I was considering this, but wanted to see if I could potentially save the drive first. Also my "required" recovery CD's are pretty old and beaten--it's a four year old laptop, they've spent a lot of time floating around in my car from moving, and I'm uneasy about relying on them. I suppose I'll just install linux if I have to.

Comment: Depending upon the model of the laptop, it should also be pretty easy to track down the required drivers online.

Comment: right, it's just I don't know which driver it is, how to find an exhaustive list of them, etc. from the recovery console.

Comment: Sounds more like a replacement drive is in order to be honest.